# Change Text BackGround Color in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="name">Tortilla de blé</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the original source. I need to change the **background Color of just the text** in the tag.
I have used css property background-color for it. But it is changing the color of the whole list item.
i have to change the background color only by using javascript.

```
var ea = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
for(var i = 0; i < ea.length; i++)
    ea[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

(Changed the Older Script as that was not correct, mistakenly written)

**My Result:**

[image: Original Image]

**Expected Result:**
What could i do to just highlight the text in the tag and not the whole tag.

[image: Expected Image]

I have produced the expected result by editing the source code like below:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="name"><font style="bakground-color:yellow">Tortilla de blé</font></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

By Embedding font tag to the text which is not possible with the javascript.
I have done this with the help of **Inspect Element** feature of Google Chrome

Comment: A point of clarification: in the 'expected result' picture, is the JS being applied only to the first list element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried with jQuery,
http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/gT9eh/

Comment: http://www.club-sandwich.net/recettes/tuna-wrap-256.php

Check this Page. I have created my example form this page

Answer (score 3):

Your js example is not valid and should not do anything ...

You need to set the style on each span element;

```
var ea = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
for(var i = 0; i < ea.length; i++)
        ea[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

Comment: fine, but i need to highlight just the text not the whole tag ... is this possible?

Comment: It will; http://jsfiddle.net/pe4bn/ unless the span is inheriting a style that overrides its default behaviour, e.g. display:block

Comment: http://www.club-sandwich.net/recettes/tuna-wrap-256.php

Check this Page. I have created my example form this page.

Comment: I am trying to highlight some text on a web page which is from a different domain.

Comment: Setting 'background: yellow;' on the <span class="name"> elements in the Chrome inspector works fine on your club-sandwich.net page - so it should be settable in JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 1):

As explained above - your JS is not valid. For starters, the function name is 'getElementsByClassName' rather than 'getElementByClaassName'.

You then need to have it loop through the elements and set their properties individually. JQuery will give you a nice shortcut as outlined by Sameera.

Answer (score 1):

**sample from Alex K.  :**

because there was an error I had to add 2 brackets :

```
var ea = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
for(var i = 0; i < ea.length; i++)
        {ea[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";}
```